# How to find a "good" extension of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, real-numbers

If I want to invent intresting new types of numbers like complex numbers with specific properties, for example $i^2=-1$ for the complex numbers, what properties must I have to be a extension of $\mathbb{R}$ that :

- Doesn't make contradictions ? Example : see [my last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035996/convergence-of-series-strange-numbers)
- Is not "equivalent" to another number ? Example : $j$ is a number such as $kj = k$ and $k+j=k+1$
- May be interesting ?

Comment: Related: [Is there a field extension over the real numbers that is not the same as the field of complex numbers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299123/is-there-a-field-extension-over-the-real-numbers-that-is-not-the-same-as-the-fie)

Comment: I don't understand the post you sent me

Comment: The invention of new numbers (and new mathematics in general) usually comes from an attempt to solve a particular problem, not from a wish to invent something "interesting". Is there a particular problem you hope to solve?

Comment: @PearlSek : your question is quite unclear/broad. Could you please make it more precise (unless my answer is satisfactory to you)?

Answer (score 1):

The algebraic closure $\Bbb C$ of $\Bbb R$ has degree $2$ over $\Bbb R$, so $\Bbb R$ has no algebraic extension except $\Bbb R$ itself and $\Bbb C$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199630/a-finite-field-extension-of-mathbb-r-is-either-mathbb-r-or-isomorphic-to?rq=1)).

I'm not sure what you can do with transcendental extensions, but you can try to work with ring extensions. For instance, the [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) $\Bbb R[\epsilon] = \Bbb R[x]/(x^2)$ can be interesting.

But your conditions $kj=k$ and $k+j=k+1$ are very strange: $k+j=k+1 \implies j=1$, so $kj=k$ is trivially satisfied, whenever $k,j \in A$ and $A$ is a commutative ring such that $\Bbb R \subset A$, and $1$ (as the real number $1$) is the unity of $A$.

Comment: Yes it was an example of the equivalence to another number

Comment: A nice way to "create" new numbers is to consider quotient rings of $\Bbb R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, e.g. $\Bbb R[x]/(x^2+1)$ is just isomorphic to $\Bbb C$.